# CSS Only Displaying Correctly in Customizer Mode

Tags: css, wordpress

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com

I recently installed a variety of new Plugins including BackWPup, Relevanssi, SumoMe, W3 Total Cache and Compress JPEG & PNG images.

My website now only loads correctly in 'customizer mode' and not 'real mode'.

I deactivated SumoMe and Compress JPEG & PNG images because I thought that may have caused the issue but it didn't solve the problem.

[image]

[image]

I have tried looking over the Additional CSS history and going into developer mode but I have not come any closer to fixing the problem.

I tested the problem in multiple browsers, on multiple devices and on multiple themes. The same issue kept appearing.

Comment: Sounds like you're getting served a cached copy of the pages. The http headers for the particular page in your photos has the following `expires=Thu, 01-Nov-18 08:42:12 GMT` You may want to clear the cache generated by W3 Cache. There is a button on the admin bar which will enable you to do so. I cannot remember the exact phrasing but it's along the lines of *purge cache*

Comment: Now be aware that it's not good practice to delete cached items which have not been changed / altered as that will slow your site down. You may need to tweak the settings of what gets purged and when according to your needs after you solve the current issue.